# LinkedIn internal API error 500 sharing with groups

Tags: api, linkedin-api, internal-server-error

We are getting several internal API errors sharing at LinkedIn groups. This is very sad, since it's not something we can fix at our end, please someone has any recommendations on have LinkedIn support for fixing this (or at least having clues on how to fixing or having a workaround from our end). Thank you !!

The request is:

- URL:

  ```
  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/1220767/posts?oauth2_access_token=*****
  ```
- METHOD:

  ```
  POST
  ```
- HEADERS:

  ```
  x-li-format:json
  Content-Length:1233
  ```
- BODY CONTENT:

  ```
  {"title":"ATENCIÓN  Nuevo Laredo?  Buscamos:  \"Gerente Regional de Operaciones\"  Aplica en http://tltk.co/hjzjDNy","summary":"-","content":{"submitted-url":"http://tltk.co/hjzjDNy","submitted-image-url":"https://www.talenteca.com/assets/images/tk-storage/company-images/TK_COMPANY_LOGO-2015_03_27_09_07_18-50227656346988818491.jpg","title":"Gerente Regional  Operaciones. Nuevo Laredo.","description":"Nuevo Laredo . \"Gerente Regional de Operaciones\" Nuevo Laredo.\r\nEscolaridad: Ingeniero Industrial, Ingeniero de transporte o Lic en Administración de Empresas. TITULADOS.\r\nInglés: 85%\r\nSexo: Indistinto\r\nExperiencia Indispensable en puesto similar de 3 a 5 años\r\n \r\nExperiencia como Gerente de Carga, embarque o tráfico, preferente en empresa de mensajería o logística administrando personal mando medio y operativo.\r\nExperiencia en distribución, logística y almacenaje.\r\n \r\nSupervisión de personal mando medio y operativo\r\nEstructura Operativa\r\nRutas locales y foráneas\r\nInvestigación de operaciones\r\nSeguridad patrimonial\r\nPlaneaciòn estratégica\r\nCriterios de embarque\r\nGuía de estiba\r\n \r\nDisponibilidad para Viajar constantemente\r\nPara trabajar en NUEVO LAREDO.\r\n "}}
  ```
- RESPONSE:

  ```
  {
  "errorCode":0,
  "message":"Internal API server error",
  "requestId":"YFEEIWUU4G",
  "status":500,
  "timestamp":1427747517095
  }
  ```

Sorry the real access token is obfuscated for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because of content type

1.Add the "*format=json*" parameter with your api url.

2.Set the content_type is application/json in the header.

Now invoke the api and see.

Comment: Now on the testing environment, will let you know how is going

Comment: We have test it this workaround but is NOT working. Any other ideas Naasheer ? ... anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to this link and check with your api creditials, weather the api works :
https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

if any issue share the error message as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was actually a LinkedIn internal issue that with the new LinkedIn API changes and deprecated services is no longer relevant.